# cannot switch to webview using appium from native context

Tags: android, python, android-webview, appium, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to access a webview from the my native context for the app but i have been unable to do so with the following error.

> WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver)

I have tried to run my script using `appium 1.3.7.2` on android emulators with multiple configurations including `4.4.2`, `5.1`, and `4.3`. none of the three seem to work and they are throwing the same error.

I have also looked into:

https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=845&thanks=845&ts=1404927199

And followed a few steps, changed the chromedriver binaries but with no luck.

I have multiple webviews present , but i dont think that should be the issue here. can somebody please help me with this ?

Please look at the following stack trace :

> o: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "ps"
>
> info: [debug] WEBVIEW_2767 mapped to pid 2767
>   info: [debug] Getting process name for webview
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "ps"
>   info: [debug] Parsed pid: 2767 pkg: ***
>   info: [debug] from: u0_a53,2767,944,800448,111104,ffffffff,b75152d2,S,**
>   info: [debug] returning process name: 
>   **info: [debug] Parsed pid: 2785 pkg:** 
>   info: [debug] from: u0_a53,2785,944,593196,52692,ffffffff,b7577355,S,
>   **info: [debug] returning process name:** 
>   info: [debug] Available contexts: NATIVE_APP,**,**
>   info: [debug] ["WEBVIEW_**","WEBVIEW_**"]
>   info: [debug] Available contexts: NATIVE_APP,WEBVIEW_**,WEBVIEW_**
>   info: [debug] Connecting to chrome-backed webview
>   info: [debug] Creating Chrome session
>   info: [debug] Set chromedriver binary as: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\chromedriver\windows\chromedriver.exe
>   info: [debug] Ensuring Chromedriver exists
>   info: [debug] Killing any old chromedrivers, running: FOR /F "usebackq tokens=5" %a in (`netstat -nao ^| findstr /R /C:"9515 "`) do (FOR /F "usebackq" %b in (`TASKLIST /FI "PID eq %a" ^| findstr /I chromedriver.exe`) do (IF NOT %b=="" TASKKILL /F /PID %b))
>   info: [debug] No old chromedrivers seemed to exist
>   info: [debug] Spawning chromedriver with: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\chromedriver\windows\chromedriver.exe
>   info: [debug] [CHROMEDRIVER] Starting ChromeDriver (v2.10.289383) on port 9515
>   Only local connections are allowed.
>   info: [debug] Making http request with opts: {"url":"http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session","method":"POST","json":{"sessionId":null,"desiredCapabilities":{"chromeOptions":{"androidPackage":"**","androidUseRunningApp":true,"androidDeviceSerial":"emulator-5554"}}}}
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver)","origValue":"Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver"},"sessionId":"ac576cc4-fea0-450d-a4bf-f2b5f2ca9dc4"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/ac576cc4-fea0-450d-a4bf-f2b5f2ca9dc4/context 500 416.371 ms - 280 
>       at Chromedriver.onClose (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\chromedriver.js:144:10)
>       at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12) context: [POST /wd/hub/session/ac576cc4-fea0-450d-a4bf-f2b5f2ca9dc4/context {"sessionId":"ac576cc4-fea0-450d-a4bf-f2b5f2ca9dc4","name":"WEBVIEW_***"}]
>   info: [debug] [CHROMEDRIVER STDERR] [0.008][SEVERE]: Could not bind socket to 127.0.0.1:9515
>   info: [debug] [CHROMEDRIVER] Port not available. Exiting...
>   info: --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/ac576cc4-fea0-450d-a4bf-f2b5f2ca9dc4 {}
>   info: Shutting down appium session
>   info: [debug] Pressing the HOME button
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "input keyevent 3"
>   info: [debug] Chromedriver exited with code 1
>   info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting down"}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Closed client connection
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Time: 53.474
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] OK (1 test)
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
>   info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
>   info: [debug] UiAutomator shut down normally
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session

Answer (score 0):

*December 5,2012.*

I hope at present this problem is resolved using AppiumDriver and then switching the context to Webview using this :

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {    
System.out.println(contextName); //prints out something like NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_com.example.android etc..}
String setContext = contextNames.toArray()[1].toString();
driver.context(setContext);// set context to WEBVIEW_com.example.android
```

Perform your action using css and classname. Switch back to Native context using `driver.context(NATIVE_APP);`